# Changing the user agent using selenium webdriver in Java

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

Can someone pls tell me how to switch the user agent using webdriver in Java?
I tried below, but getting errors.

```
FirefoxProfile ffp = new FirefoxProfile(); 
ffp.setPreference("general.useragent.override",
"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:15.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/15.0");
WebDriver fd = new FirefoxDriver(ffp);
```

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: What syntax errors? Can you share the message text of the errors?

Comment: Does it say which line?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[DesiredCapabilities](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/DesiredCapabilities) would help you to change user agent.

You can achieve this by calling these methods:

- `setBrowserName(java.lang.String browserName)`
- `setPlatform(Platform platform)`
- `setVersion(java.lang.String version)`

**Or**

- `static DesiredCapabilities chrome()`
- `static DesiredCapabilities firefox()`
- `static DesiredCapabilities iphone()`
- ...

More [here](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/remote/DesiredCapabilities.html).

Comment: Hey both the links seemed to be changed. Can you please update them?

Answer (score 9):

I believe this solution is the desired answer to the question. I tested it and it worked for me. Happy coding!

```
FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
String userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.103 Safari/537.36 OPR/60.0.3255.170";
options.addPreference("general.useragent.override",userAgent);

WebDriver webDriver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
webDriver.get("http://whatsmyuseragent.org");
```

Answer (score 5):

I needed to do it for Chrome, and needed to set a specific string (not fitting as platform, browser or version) for Googlebot.

```
    // import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;

    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addArguments("user-agent=\"Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)\"");
    new ChromeDriver(options);
```