# Selenium WebDriver - Java - Changing the User Agent

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

i am currently going through selenium webdriver on the selenium wbesite.

There is a section of the website that talks about the "Change user agent" and explains how to do it: https://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#chapter03-reference However, no "real" or "mock" example is given showing this in "action".

So, I was wondering if anyone here, would perhaps have or be able to share a code snippet, with the project included, showing this "in action"? A mock project, you may have or designed yourself to practice this, should suffice.

I have already made a lot of research online, trying to find an example of this, but no success.

Answer (score 4):

From the link you provided, you can change the `User-Agent` with below code:

Firefox:

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.addAdditionalPreference("general.useragent.override", "user-agent-string");
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

Chrome:

```
ChromeOptions chrome = new ChromeOptions();
chrome.addArguments("user-agent=YOUR_USER_AGENT");
```

It's `Java` but you can easily switch to any selenium-supported language because all of them implement `FirefoxProfile` and `ChromeOptions`

Comment: Hi there @Fenio, thank you for your answer. However, I am after a full "block of code" example from a project showing this embedded in it.

Comment: @PeterR That's now what this portal is about. We can answer your question, not implement the entire solution for you

Comment: @PeterR Besides, it would work. You would just have to provide property for driver executable and run the program...

Comment: @PeterR See https://stackoverflow.com/a/57316139/1545579 for a slightly more complete example.