# Can't login sites using Selenium Webdriver (Java)

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Some reason it can't login to the website. After typing the user name and password, he clicks on the login button, but for some reason, when the login button is clicked, the required process does not work. It happen like the page has been refreshed.

```
public class main extends baseTest {
@Test
public void gittiGidiyor() throws Exception {
    boolean logo = displayElement(By.cssSelector("[alt='GittiGidiyor']"));
    if (logo) {
        logger.info("Main Page.");
    } else {
        logger.info("not Main Page");
        fail();
    }
    assertName(driver.getTitle(),"GittiGidiyor");
    clickElement(By.xpath("(//*[@class='gekhq4-4 egoSnI'])[1]"));
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    clickElement(By.cssSelector("[class='qjixn8-0 sc-1bydi5r-0 kNKwwK']"));
    sendElement(By.id("L-UserNameField"), "blabla@hotmail.com");
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    sendElement(By.id("L-PasswordField"), "blabla11");
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    clickElement(By.id("gg-login-enter"));
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    boolean account = displayElement(By.cssSelector("[title='Account'] [class='gekhq4-4 egoSnI']"));
    if (account) {
        logger.info("login successful.");
    } else {
        logger.info("login unsuccessful.");
        fail();
    }
```

**clickElement(By.id("gg-login-enter"));** This line should be work but i don't know why, it just doesn't.
[Video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5xOw1.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I've tried same thing with different site which ended exactly the same. But the solution I came up with is when the login page is opened I manually enter the login infos and check like this:

```
while(!account){
  account = displayElement(By.cssSelector("[title='Account'] [class='gekhq4-4 egoSnI']"));
  Thread.sleep(5000);
}
```

Comment: It works when I do it that way. But this process needs to progress by itself.

Comment: @Berkan as you know once you logged in you can use it til you logout.

Comment: This project will run on another computer so it's very important that it runs automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an **Agent**. You can use the URL below for the solution.

[Changing the user agent using selenium webdriver in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18484317/changing-the-user-agent-using-selenium-webdriver-in-java)